# Select all rows from a model and have a nested json element as the Foreign key to another model with all rows selected

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I would like my JSON element returned by my controller to look like this

```
{           
    "model": "Ford",
    "make": "GT350R",
    "dealerName": "Dallas Ford",
    "location": {
        "dealerName": "Dallas Ford",
        "zip": 05700,
    }
}
```

I cant seem to get the query right in my controller. **I want to select all rows and every element from the Cars Model and where there is a foreign key to the location Table. I then want to embed all the rows that belong to that location element into a sub element.** I think i may need to tell my models about the foreign key but because i am using the same attribute name i think Entity Framework 6 does it for me.

This is the code I am trying which will only select all the results from Cars it wont show the location as a nested element.

```
var query = (from results in db.Cars
             join location in db.Locations on results.DealerName equals location.Dealername
             select results);
return Ok(query.ToList());
```

This is the json that it shows for each element

```
{ 
    "model": "Ford",
    "make": "GT350R",
    "dealerName": "Dallas Ford",
}
```

Here are my models

**Car model**

```
//......
[Key]
public string make { get; set; }
public string model { get; set; }
public Location Locations{ get; set; }//added this because someone in comments said to
public string dealerName { get; set; }
//........
```

**Location** model

```
//......
[Key]
public string dealername{ get; set; }
public string Zip { get; set; }
//........
```

And heres what i think the code should look like but I am not doing it right.

```
var query = (from results in db.Cars
             join location in db.Locations on results.DealerName equals location.Dealername
             select new {
                 results = results;
                 results.location = location;
             });
return Ok(query.ToList());
```

Comment: You may want to change your key to utilize an integer or unique identifier in case there are duplicate Dealership names - a very possible scenario.

Comment: its just an example not a real app. Im trying to learn how to query across tables and embed the table i join with as a sub element in the json.

Comment: Your location model needs to be a property of the Car model to obtain the desired json.

Comment: oh neat so in the Car model i need to have public Location locationHolder {get;set}. How do i set it?

Comment: Modify the setter. See [MSDN Reference on using properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

Comment: Your model should have [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/jj713564.aspx) and then this will be handles out of the box using `var query = db.Cars.Include(x => x.location);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    var query = (from results in db.Cars
                 join location in db.Locations on results.dealerName equals location.dealerName 
                 select new {
                   model = results.model, make = results.make, dealerName = results.dealerName, location = location }     
             );
                return json(query.ToList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your life simpler and use the Entity Framework syntax. Even though you *can* use LINQ to SQL, it's just so much more verbose and problematic to work with. All you need is:

```
var query = db.Cars.Where(m => m.Locations.Any()).Include(m => m.Locations);
```

Comment: is there a url for the API for Entity framework syntax. I am new to .net entity framework and linq so I typically just modify examples from old SO posts without knowing what format they are in.

Comment: There's no one-stop shop, unless you just dig through the actual namespace docs on MSDN. However, this comes pretty close, I think: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907#using

Comment: any idea on what the following error means?  'Location' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'Location' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)